# How do I pass an object to @Input in Angular app rendering as a story in StoryBook

Tags: json, angular, typescript, storybook

My component *blopp* has the following structure.

```
@Component({ selector: 'blopp', template: '{{config|json}}', ... })
export class BloppComponent {
  @Input() config: Config; ...    
}
```

While the config itself is a class shown below.

```
export class Config {
  constructor(public id: string, public title: string, public active: boolean) { }
}
```

It all seems to work when I set up a test in StoryBook like this.

```
export const test1 = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: '<plopp [config]="{id:23,title:22,active:true}"></plopp>'
});
```

I'd like to set up an object and pass it. However, trying to do the following doesn't render anything, as if the passed entity is *null* or *undefined*. What is the proper syntax for it?

```
export const test2 = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: '<plopp [config]=config></plopp>'
});

export const test3 = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: '<plopp [config]="config"></plopp>'
});

export const test4 = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: '<plopp [config]=configText></plopp>'
});

export const test5 = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: '<plopp [config]="configText"></plopp>'
});

const config = new Config("a1", "donkey", true);
const configText = JSON.stringify(config);
```

I've tried a bunch of variants only leading to failures and nothing rendered. Is it a limitation in StoryBook? I suspect rather that it's my incompetence that's to blame but I'm ignorant of approach it.

The closest I got was this. It still won't let me enter a string for *title*, though (the quotations are misinterpreted). And in the end, that's not really like-a-bossy. I want to use an actual object and pass it in.

```
export const test5 = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: '<plopp [config]=' + configText + '></plopp>'
});

const configText = "{id:23,title:34,active:true}";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a big fan of answering my own junk but the colleague who presented me with the solution is one of those weirdo leeches who refuses to contribute to the site (because *oh, oh, once I asked a question and people were mean 'cause it sucked and I got my ego hurt...*). So just to be clear - I haven't figured out it self. Oscar did. And it was easy.

Apparently, StoryBook requires oneself to provide the variable values using a special field in the configuration object of the story. So the moronically easy solution to my moronically stupid problem is to add *config* as *props*, like so.

```
export const useGodDamnProps = () => ({
  ...componentModule,
  template: "<plopp [config]='config'></plopp>",
  props: { config }
});
```

Comment: Awesome comment :-)

Comment: @ekimpl I see no comment (awesome or regular one). What did you refer to? (I sense that I'm missing something and got curious... Awesome stuff is fun to read.)

Comment: Your comment about Oscar :-)

Comment: @ekimpl Ah, haha, I got me a nice laugh once I re-read my own formulation. I guess I was PO'ed at him and it's wiser to be funny than obnoxious. And I agree - it is an awesome comment.    :)

Comment: You seem like a lovely person to work with. That's sarcasm, by the way.

Comment: @paddotk Thank you for sharing your sentiment on a matter that doesn't involve you and in a context that is over 3 years old. Also, if one has to declare that their statement is a sarcasm, it's a sign of poor skills in linguistics. In such case, it's probably advised to keep the message more direct to avoid a sad aftertaste. That said, you might not find my personally enjoyable to work with. It likely says more about you that me, though. Cheers to you mate and happy coding! I recommend FaceBook to share your emotions, keeping StackOverflow clear if such.

Comment: @KonradViltersten indeed it doesn't concern me, nor anyone here. So why post it? Keep your childish negative shenanigans to yourself. Or use Facebook.

Comment: @paddotk You wrote with negative tone and irrelevant remark. I only responded. Also, I have no need to cry out my pains, so I don't use FaceBook (nor harass users on StackOverflow). Please accept my apology for engaging in your comment. I should have disregarded you and stand above petty hostilities. You may have had a bad day and I should be more understanding. I'm sorry for that and I promise you to ignore such misconduct henceforth. Let's keep it dignified and not continue, unless you feel the need to have the last word, in which case, please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template: `<plopp [config]="${configText}"></plopp>`
```

Comment: Have you tested it or just guessing? I asking so because it looks like a common interpolation, while the problem is about the value not being rendered. You might want to peek at the answer next to your. That one worked. What is the purpose of the dollar sign and does it related to StoryBook?

Answer (score 0):

This could help as an example: https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/composite-component/

```
    // default TaskList state
export const Default = () => ({
  component: TaskListComponent,
  template: `
  <div style="padding: 3rem">
    <app-task-list [tasks]="tasks" (onPinTask)="onPinTask($event)" (onArchiveTask)="onArchiveTask($event)"></app-task-list>
  </div>
`,
  props: {
    tasks: defaultTasksData,
    onPinTask: actionsData.onPinTask,
    onArchiveTask: actionsData.onArchiveTask,
  },
});
```